# Why does this program output 1?

Tags: java, oop

I've looked at this code and I don't understand why this program will print `1` .

First of all, in `foo(myObject)` we are assigning something to final, how is this possible?

And the second thing, after `foo()` was done, we'll get `myObject` to be null, so how can we even print it?

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myInt;
    public static void foo(MyClass myObject) {
        myObject.myInt = 1;
        myObject = null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.myInt = 2;
        foo(myObject);
        System.out.println(myObject.myInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `myObject.myInt = 1`. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @bradimus It's not as simple as that... the object is being set to null before the print statement, which can cause confusion for those not familiar with Java.

Comment: Do you know how java pass the objects to another methods????

Comment: @MatthewDiana, you're right that there is potential confusion there, so I would think you might be more careful with your language.  It is not *the object* that is being set null, but rather one *reference* to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: @Tom: Not on its own, no. (Part of the problem with two-part questions. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And we all know that one should ask one question per post ;P.

Comment: @Tom: True that. :-) Sometimes it's hard for people to realize they're asking two questions. Here it seems like they did, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, I didnt know that 2 question in the same post was a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> First of all, in `foo(myObject)` we are assigning something to `final`, how is it possisble?

The *object* is not `final`, the *variable* in `main` is `final`. So in `main`, if you added `myObject = somethingElse;` after your initial line that sets its value, it wouldn't compile because you can't put a new value in the **variable**. That has no effect on whether the object the variable refers to is mutable.

> And the second thing, after `foo()` was done, we'll get `myObject` to be null, so how can we even print it?

There are two *separate* things called `myObject` in your code:

1. A variable in `main`
2. A parameter in `foo`

Your code in `foo` sets the *parameter* to `null`, but that has no effect whatsoever on the variable in `main`. (In fact, it's impossible for `foo` to have any effect on the variable in `main`; Java is a purely pass-by-value language. All `foo` can do, as you've demonstrated, is modify the state of the object that both the variable and the parameter refer to, using the object reference passed into it as a parameter.)

Let's stop your code just before this line in `foo`:

```
myObject.myInt = 1;
```

Here's what we have in memory (leaving out some details and irrelevancies):

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        | variable "myObject"  |           foo can change the
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           *state* of this
foo can't change this−−>| Ref22458             |−−−+                   |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                   v
                                                   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−>| object of type MyClass |
                        | parameter "myObject" |   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |    | myInt: 2               |
foo can change this−−−−>| Ref22458             |−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...where "Ref22458" is just a name for the value of the object reference that points to the object you created in `main`.

Once we execute the two lines in `foo`:

```
myObject.myInt = 1;
myObject = null;
```

we have this in memory:

```
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        | variable "myObject"  |           foo can change the
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+           *state* of this
foo can't change this−−>| Ref22458             |−−−+                   |
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |                   v
                                                   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   +−−−>| object of type MyClass |
                        | parameter "myObject" |   |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+   |    | myInt: 1               |
foo can change this−−−−>| null                 |−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Note how `foo` could change the state of the object (`myInt` is now `1`), and could change the value in the *parameter* `myObject` (it's now `null`), but couldn't change the value in the *variable* `myObject` (for two reasons: it has no access to the variable [Java is pass-by-value], and the variable is `final`).

Answer (score 0):

Java is not pass by reference (references are passed by value), assigning `myObject` to `null` does not make a difference. It is not `final` neither, because it is not made final inside your `foo()` method. It prints 1, because you pass the reference of `myObject` into `foo()` and set its field. It's still a mutable object, so its value is updated.

Answer (score 0):

`final` just specifies that the object itself should not change - when used with classes like your code it just prevents someone from doing `myObject = ...`. Unless you mark `MyClass.myInt` final, you will be able to assign whatever value to the int that you want, even after assignment.

The way to solve this is to make `myInt` private and provide a public getter for it instead, preventing it from being modified (except by reflection)

Comment: But myObject = null  is happning inside of foo(), isnt that an assiment to final ?

Comment: @limitless No. Those are distinct reference in distinct scopes.

Comment: @limitless That only applies within the scope of `foo()`. You're not setting `myObject` that was declared as final in `main`, you're setting the argument `myObject` for the `foo` method.